# self.rect not found?

Tags: python, pygame, rect

I have a program that is simply made to move an image around. I try to state the self.rect as part of a load_png() call, but it simply does not like it. THe reason I think this will work is from http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/tom/games6.html, saying that this should work:

```
def __init__(self, side):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.image, self.rect = load_png('bat.png')
            screen = pygame.display.get_surface()
            self.area = screen.get_rect()
            self.side = side
            self.speed = 10
            self.state = "still"
            self.reinit()
```

Here is my code, which according to the pygame tutorial from its own website, should work:

```
def _init_(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite._init_(self)
    self.state = 'still'
    self.image =  pygame.image.load('goodGuy.png')
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()       
    screen = pygame.display.getSurface()
```

And it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python25\RPG.py", line 37, in <module>
screen.blit(screen, Guy.rect, Guy.rect)
AttributeError: 'goodGuy' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

If you guys need all of my code, comment blew and I will edit it.

Comment: Do you have a load_png function defined as per the link you provided?

Comment: AhHA! I assumed that was a built in python function. return image.get_rect() will suffice, correct?

Comment: It's defined in the code example you gave us.

Comment: You need to create an image using pygame.image.load and this will have a rect property. See my answer below.

Comment: The error you're getting is occurring outside of the code that you have posted.  You will need to post that code as well.  Also, why are you blitting the `screen` on itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a load_png function defined.

You need to create the pygame image object before you can access its rect property.

```
self.image = pygame.image.load(file)
```

Then you can assign the rect value using

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Or you could create the load_png function as per the example you linked.

Comment: You need to execute the function self.image.get_rect() - you need the parentheses. In your code you just have self.image.get_rect.

Comment: Well firstly; the function should be __ init __ (note the double underscores). You only have single underscores (unless that is a typo).

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know you needed double underscores. Thanks for putting up with this.

Comment: No worries at all. If this has helped you it might be worthwhile accepting the answer to help others who may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `load_png` function built-in to python or pygame.  I imagine that the tutorial you are referring to defined it manually somewhere.  What you want is [`pygame.image.load(filename)`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html#pygame.image.load) and then you can call [`get_rect()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.get_rect) on the returned Surface object.  The complete code would be as follows:

```
self.image = pygame.image.load('bat.png')
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Your second problem is that you've defined the function `_init_`, but you need double underscores: `__init__`.

Also, you need to post the code where the error is actually occurring.