# Having trouble getting clicked sprites in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate, but I've followed numerous pages on this site trying to find an answer, and I haven't been able to get one to work yet. 
Some of the pages I've used are:

[Pygame mouse clicking detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990137/pygame-mouse-clicking-detection)

[self.rect not found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715877/self-rect-not-found)

[how does collide.rect work in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15146679/how-does-collide-rect-work-in-pygame)

It may be my lack of coding comprehension, and I apologize if that's the case. However, I found the most "helpful" page to be the first link. Using Sloth's first answer, it seemed very simple and something I would be able to do. Once his method did not work, I tried searching around even more for on YouTube and other sites. I also couldn't find an answer.

All I want to do is simply print "clicked" when a sprite is clicked. Here is my code.

```
import pygame
size = (700,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
itunes = pygame.image.load('itunes.png')
screen.blit(itunes,(200,200))
sprites = [itunes]
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            clicked_sprites = [s for s in sprites if s.rect.collidepoint(pos)]
            for i in clicked_sprites:
                print('clicked sprite')
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

I've learned very little of the Python language, but I found myself getting bored making the same text-based programs and would like to move on.

EDIT: I'm sorry, I should have stated what error I was getting. I'm getting: AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'

EDIT: Having trouble drawing the image on the screen

```
import pygame
size = (700,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
white = (0,0,0)
image = 'itunes.png'
class Thing(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('itunes.png')
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def rect(self):
        return self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y))

itunes = Thing(image,200,200)

SpriteGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()    
SpriteGroup.add(itunes)                

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            clicked_sprites = [s for s in SpriteGroup if s.rect.collidepoint(pos)]
            for i in clicked_sprites:
                print('clicked sprite')
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))             
    SpriteGroup.draw(screen)           
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images are `pygame.Surface` objects, and they don't have a `rect` as an attribute. You can *get* one for that Surface object, however, by calling `SurfaceObject.get_rect()`. This will create a `pygame.Rect` object that represents the dimensions of the Surface, if not its position.

Depending on how often your object would create a new `rect` or modify it based on its position in the window, you might subclass `pygame.sprite.Sprite` and use a property to retrieve the Rect at its correct position. For example:

```
class Thing(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, x, y):
        super(Thing, self).__init__()    #don't forget to do this!! (like I did :D, haha)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(image)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def rect(self):
        return self.image.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y))
```

The `surface.get_rect()` call takes keyword arguments that allow you to set attributes of the object as it's being created. In this way, it's basically a one-liner for:

```
new_rect = self.image.get_rect()
new_rect.x = self.x
new_rect.y = self.y
return new_rect
```

This whole process returns a rect which is in the correct position in the window, such that it can be used for collision detection or just to see if it's the object that was clicked as in your example.

Another upshot of this approach (using a property for the `rect`) is that it makes the object work well with the `pygame.sprite.Group.draw()` method, which draws all `Sprite` objects in that `Group` object by blitting their `obj.image` and `obj.rect` attributes.

So you take advantage of this by turning `sprites` from a `list` to a sprite.Group object, and making the following changes to your code:

```
SpriteGroup = pygame.sprite.Group()    #use these for working with Sprite objects
SpriteGroup.add(itunes)                #add itunes to sprites Group
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            clicked_sprites = [s for s in sprites if s.rect.collidepoint(pos)]
            for i in clicked_sprites:
                print('clicked sprite')
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))             #wipes the screen
    SpriteGroup.draw(screen)           #draws every Sprite object in this Group
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm now able to click on the screen and it will print out "clicked sprite" whenever I click in it's collision points. however, now I just don't know how to draw the image onto the screen... Before I was using `screen.blit(itunes,(200,200))` which gives me the error "TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not Thing" and I'm not really sure what to do from here.

Comment: Before, `itunes` was a `Surface`. The `screen.blit` method is a `Surface` method (your `pygame.display.set_mode()` call returns the window as a Surface). `Surface.blit()` takes two arguments: a Surface and a Rect. The `Thing` Sprite has obj.image and obj.rect, and these should suffice for `screen.blit`. Alternatively, I would suggest making your `sprites` list a `pygame.sprite.Group()` object, and then calling `sprites.draw(screen)` to automatically take care of the blitting. This will automatically iterate over any sprites in the Group and blit their .image and .rect attributes to `screen`.

Comment: Also -- I don't know what kind of app you're creating, but 60 FPS is a lot. If this is a game, then I suppose it makes sense, but if it's some kind of app, you can probably bring that way down

Comment: Thanks again :D. I'm so close to getting this to work... I'm still having a bit of trouble though. So you said I should change the sprites list to a SpriteGroup. So I changed that, but I noticed that the list `clicked_sprites` is still iterating through sprites in the code. 
I tried changing it to `SpriteGroup` but now I'm getting another error, "AttributeError: 'Thing' object has no attribute '_Sprite__g'" 
I updated my post with the code I'm using now

Comment: bah, that's my bad -- you have to call super() during the init

Comment: Also -- your collidepoint bit is fine, you don't necessarily need that to *not* be a list.

Comment: Everything works perfectly. Thank you for your help. Turns out I REALLY have A LOT more to learn about Python... Never even heard of a super before.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at what you code does.

- You load a new image into the itunes variable.
- You blit this image onto the screen at 200,200
- You add the image into the sprite list.
- When you click the mouse you loop the sprite list to check if the mouse point lies in the  rect of the objects in the sprite list.

Now how do we know the position of the objects that are in the sprite list? The answer is that we don't. There is no information about the position of the object in the surface itself.

To solve this you can make your own Sprite class that will include a `rect` and a surface, or more preferably use `pygame.sprite.Sprite` which already includes rect.